Avoid double quotes when querying Oracle tables created by EF Core 8 Code First
Background
I have a table model like this:
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Author { get; set; } = default!;
    public int Pages { get; set; } = default!;
}

If I run my add migration command
dotnet ef migrations add AddBooks -p .\MyApplication.Infrastructure\ -s .\MyApplication.API\

I get the expected outcome:
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Books",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "RAW(16)", nullable: false),
        Name = table.Column<string>(type: "NVARCHAR2(2000)", nullable: false),
        Author = table.Column<string>(type: "NVARCHAR2(2000)", nullable: false),
        Pages = table.Column<int>(type: "NUMBER(10)", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Books", x => x.Id);
    });

If I then update the database:
dotnet ef database update -p .\MyApplication.Infrastructure\ -s .\MyApplication.API\

The table is created as specified:

Where it goes wrong
What I expect to see is that I can query my table like this:
select * from Books b

However it states that Table or view does not exist.
If I generate my query it does that like this:
select * from "Books" b

That works correctly but it is different to how all other tables are set up.
My question

How can I generate my table(s) without needing those extra double
quotes?


Oracle is case-sensitive. However, the default behaviour is to convert all unquoted identifiers to upper-case so that it appears to be case-insensitive. Therefore:
select * from Books
select * from books
select * from BoOkS
select * from BOOKS

Would all select from a table called BOOKS (upper-case) and are equivalent.
Quoted identifiers are used to enforce case-sensitivity in an identifier. Therefore:
select * from "Books"
select * from "books"
select * from "BoOkS"
select * from "BOOKS"

Would select from four different tables - Books, books, BoOkS and BOOKS respectively and only the last query is the equivalent of the queries using unquoted identifiers.

When you create the migration, you are generating a table named Books (in mixed-case) this means if you want to access it you will need to use a quoted identifier with the exact case:
select * from "Books"

Alternatively, you need to modify your EF code to generate upper-case identifiers in the migrations:
[Table("BOOKS")]
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Column("NAME")]
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
    [Column("AUTHOR")]
    public string Author { get; set; } = default!;
    [Column("PAGES")]
    public int Pages { get; set; } = default!;
}

Then you will be able to use unquoted identifiers (in any case) in your queries.
Else look to see if there is a migration setting that will change the case of all the identifiers to upper-case so you can use unquoted identifiers.
Addendum
If you add nuget package
EFCore.NamingConventions
to the project that holds your DbContext and override OnConfiguring you can do the following:
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseUpperSnakeCaseNamingConvention();

    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}

This will cause the Books table to be created like this:
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "BOOKS",
    columns: table => new
    {
        ID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "RAW(16)", nullable: false),
        NAME = table.Column<string>(type: "NVARCHAR2(2000)", nullable: false),
        AUTHOR = table.Column<string>(type: "NVARCHAR2(2000)", nullable: false),
        PAGES = table.Column<int>(type: "NUMBER(10)", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_BOOKS", x => x.ID);
    });


That was easy ... I would prefer a migration setting over having to manually annotate everything. I will hold off accepting as an answer for now in the hopes someone (or you) can provide that info. (If it takes too long I will just accept)

@kbd I don't know the answer for the migration settings - however if you look at the Using a Migration Operation documentation it gives an example of how to override the SQL that is generated and the example includes the line .Append(sqlHelper.DelimitIdentifier(operation.Name)) if it was changed to .Append(operation.Name) then the generated query would be using unquoted identifiers (but may also be vulnerable to SQL injection). ...

You need to investigate whether something similar is possible for tables (and understand the implications).

I found it. I have edited your answer to have a single solution.

@kbd I was just adding something similar - however your edit was slightly more comprehensive.
